# iPhone UIComponents are blurry @1x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

We are experiencing a strange blurring effect on some of our app screens.  It happens only on 320x480 screens of the iPhone 3x, and not on the iPhone4.  It is happening on some UIComponents - text blurring on UILabel, and image blurring on the UIImageView.  Any ideas about what's happening here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when the frames are off by 0.5 pixels. So instead of the label's frame's origin being at (100,200), for example, it is at (100.5, 200). Check how you calculate the frames, and if you are doing any division, make sure you cast the value into an int.

Comment: Whenever you are done calculating your frames just set the frame using `CGRect CGRectIntegral(CGRect rect)`